# Xamarin Shell.BackgroundColor is wrong

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my AppShell I am setting the background color of the shell, like this:

```
<Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="#0075BE" />
```

However, when the app runs in an iOS emulator, the title bar actually has a BackgroundColor of `#2588C6` (I checked with a color picker).
In an Android emulator, the color is closer at `#0073C1`, but still incorrect.

How do I get the title bar to be the actual color that I have specified?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783581/xamarin-forms-4-0-shell-titleview-ios-cannot-set-black-background-color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms 4.0 Shell TitleView iOS cannot set black background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783581/xamarin-forms-4-0-shell-titleview-ios-cannot-set-black-background-color)

Comment: That was the solution, thanks Francis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line in AppDelegate.cs

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;
```

Comment: I actually no longer work on the project that I was working on when I asked this question, but this was the solution if memory serves

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with [Xamarin.Forms Shell Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers)

**IOS:**

```
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xaminals.AppShell), typeof(Xaminals.iOS.MyShellRenderer))]
namespace Xaminals.iOS
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellSectionRenderer CreateShellSectionRenderer(ShellSection shellSection)
        {
            var renderer = base.CreateShellSectionRenderer(shellSection);
            if (renderer != null)
            {
                (renderer as ShellSectionRenderer).NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
                (renderer as ShellSectionRenderer).NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            }
            return renderer;
        }
    }
}
```

**Android:**

```
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xaminals.AppShell), typeof(Xaminals.Droid.MyShellRenderer))]
namespace Xaminals.Droid
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(this);
        }
    }

    public class MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker : ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(IShellContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public override void SetAppearance(Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(toolbar, toolbarTracker, appearance);
            toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#0075BE"));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. the iOS version is giving me error: `The type or namespace name 'AppShell' does not exist in the namespace 'Xaminals' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` ..?

Comment: @danwellman Okey, `AppShell` is my project .cs file Inherited from `Xamarin.Forms.Shell` ,just replace with your .cs file name.